# C3D Importer does not work, Context is incorrect error

Tags: import, file-format

I'm trying to import a `*.c3d` motion capture file into Blender, but when I click the *Import C3D* button, I get the following error:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are in **Object Mode** before you import!

You could also add a mode switch command to the import script:

`bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)`

Comment: After months of blender, and years of CAD experience, I still find Blender's logic very strange. Thanks, I will try that and let you know :)